# CircleGraph custom View Android

Tags: android, android-canvas, android-custom-view

I am thinking about a view of my android app having a circle graph much like image below, but instead just two colors. One color to represent amount and questions answered correctly and the other color for incorrect answers.  I was wondering if anyone knew of a custom view that may already exist or examples on how to do this using canvas.

Again, the image below is more complex than i need.  but in a nutshell i will be taking the total number of questions and drawing a green stroke around the circle representing the percentage answered correct, and then the remainder of the circle in red.

[image]

Comment: Have a look at Canvas.drawArc where your sweep angles will be based on each slice you want to show as a percentage of 360.

Comment: have a look on this https://github.com/Pedramrn/CircularProgressBar